# Best way to explain ROS to an audience with no previous knowledge

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

What would be the best way to explain ROS to an audience with no previous knowledge.Preferably in one slide.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229098/best-way-to-explain-ros-to-an-audience-with-no-previous-knowledge/) by [blane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25521/blane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-15**:
And what is your target audience? 'No knowledge' is really nothing. They will probably know something, right?

**Comment by [blane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25521/blane/) on 2016-03-15**:
The target audience is Computer Science Undergraduates with no exposure to ROS and robotics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally, I would copy pasta text and pictures from the [website](http://www.ros.org/core-components/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System). I'd pick and choose things from those sources based on the audience. No need redoing something that someone has already put time into doing.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-15**:
I've seen OSRF basically present that same website, starting at http://www.ros.org/is-ros-for-me/ , to programmers and companies when introducing ROS to them.